# First order logic expression of "Each finite state automaton has an equivalent push-down automaton"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

**Problem is**

---

> Let fsa and pda be two predicates such that fsa(x) means x is a finite
>   state automaton and pda(y) means that y is a pushdown automaton. Let
>   equivalent be another predicate such that equivalent(a,b) means a and
>   b are equivalent. Which of the following first order logic statements
>   represent the following?
>
> ```
>       Each finite state automaton has an equivalent pushdown automaton
> ```

---

**I try to explain**

---

∀x fsa(x)→(∃y pda(y)∧equivalent(x,y))

---

[It is given here](http://gateoverflow.in/441/gate2008_30)

(∀x fsa(x))→(∃y pda(y)∧equivalent(x,y))

---

I have doubt is there typo or , is (∀x fsa(x))→(∃y pda(y)∧equivalent(x,y)) also true ?

Comment: What is the correct answer for this question? Why Option C is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second formula, x is not even bounded in the second part, so $$(∀x~ fsa(x))→(∃y~ pda(y)∧equivalent(x,y))$$ contains a free variable.

Even considering its universal closure, it would not mean what you want.

Comment: I agree. The second expression is not a sentence, since the second occurrence of $x$ in it is not bounded.